# jQuery mobile grid to look like app home screen

Tags: android, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to build a responsive layout for a jQuery mobile app. The idea is to have it look a bit like the iphone home page with icons with a bit of a twist the grid should be 2 x 4 (with one row overlapping the full width)

I have it so it displays the grid fine, however I can't work out how to make it use CSS to go full screen. This is for Android/iPhone Phonegap app so the devices are going to be full screen and different sizes (so no fixed sizes can be used)

```
  <div class="ui-grid-a" style="height:33%;" >
                <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">Alerts</a></div></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e"><a href="#addpet" class="ui-btn">Add Pet</a></div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-a" style="height:33%;" >
                <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e"><a href="#listpets" class="ui-btn">Manage Pet</a></div></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" ><a href="#latlong" class="ui-btn">Manage Profile</a></div></div>
            </div>
            <div  style="height:33%" ><a href="#" class="ui-btn">Lost Pet</a></div></div>
        <div class="ui-grid-a" style="height:33%;" >
            <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">News Feed</a></div></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e"><a href="#" class="ui-btn">Mange Lost Pets</a></div></div>

        </div>
```

Above is what I have which works to a degree but it doesn't automatically space down across the screen, bunches up to the top.

Here's what it comes up with now:

[image]

Here's what I'm trying to achieve (very roughly, will be swapping the buttons out for icons soon)

[image]

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it would help if you posted some of your css. Right now, we have no idea where the styling is coming from.

Comment: Ah sorry, it's all stock jquery mobile CSS and then i've inline tried to style it down

Comment: `display: flex;` is responsive and easier to manipulate.

Comment: Thank you Omar, would you mind elaborating on that?